# stopping automated tests node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine and Zombie JS to write some automated testing. I'm using Drone.io for Continuous integration, and my tests are running fine. The problem is that once the tests are run, the output shows that they passed, but then it never seems to finish so the builds always fail. Is there a way to stop the tests after they pass?

Here is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCwMi.jpg

and my basic test:

```
 var Browser = require("zombie");
 var url = "http://localhost:3000";
 var browser = new Browser();
 console.log("RUNNING THE TEST")
describe("testing with zombie", function() {

it("should have defined headless browser", function(next){
    expect(typeof browser != "undefined").toBe(true);
    expect(browser instanceof Browser).toBe(true);
    next();
});

it("should visit the site and see the title", function(next) {
    browser.visit(url, function(err) {
        expect(browser.html("h1")).toContain("Hello!");

        next();

    })
});

 });
```

Comment: Note: I know when I run the tests through command line, i can just do control + c to stop the tests... But I can't do that with Continuous Integration. (I don't think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was passing in next into the it call back function... for the last test that gets run you need to pass in done, and then call done() at the end of the test.